# Request for Assistance in Implementing Cross-Platform Session Management with Laravel Fortify and Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, laravel-sanctum

**Problem Description:**
I have developed an application using Laravel, which includes both a website and mobile apps built with Flutter. Currently, I am able to manage browser sessions effectively using the Fortify package on the website. However, I am facing challenges when it comes to managing web sessions alongside mobile sessions. My goal is to display all active user sessions on both the web and mobile platforms, allowing users to log out from all sessions except the current one.

*Here is my current api login method:*

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $credentials = $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
                'device_name' => 'sometimes|max:100',
            ]);
        } catch (ValidationException $errors) {
            return $this->validationErrorResponse($errors);
        }


        $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();

        if (!$user || !Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }

        // Remove last authentication token for this device
        if ($request->has('device_name')) {
            $this->removeLastToken($request->device_name, $user);
        }

        $token =  $user->createToken($request->has('device_name') ? $request->device_name : "api-token")->plainTextToken;

        // Prepare user data for response
        $data = $this->prepareData($user, $token);

        return response()->json([
            'response_code' => '200',
            'response_message' => 'success',
            'user' => $data
        ], 200);
    }

    private function removeLastToken(string $device_name, User $user)
    {
        $lastToken = DB::table('personal_access_tokens')
            ->where('name', $device_name)
            ->where('tokenable_id', $user->id)
            ->first();

        if ($lastToken) {
            $lastTokenId = $lastToken->id;
            $user->tokens()->where('id', $lastTokenId)->delete();
        }
    }
```

I'm using Postman to send login requests, receiving a token in response, and then using this token for other API requests protected by the *auth:sanctum* middleware. However, I'm facing an issue with the sessions table. When I send a GET request with the {Accept: application/json, Referer: localhost:8000} header and the correct bearer token, I can see the correct user session in the sessions table, even from Postman. But as soon as I send a POST request with the same header and the correct bearer token, I get a CSRF-TOKEN mismatch error. And when I send a POST request with just {Accept: application/json} and the correct bearer token, the user_id in the sessions table becomes null, making it seem like the session doesn't exist. **The problem is that the session should not reset on each POST request.**

**Configuration Details:**

.env file:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:8000,localhost,localhost:8000
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SESSION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1:8000
```

app\Http\Kernel.php:

```
'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'throttle:api',
    // \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

config\cors.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

**Requested Solution:**

I am seeking advice and guidance on how to implement a session management logic that is compatible with both API and web access. Specifically, I would like to:

Ensure that when a user logs in via the mobile app, their session is stored in the database, allowing them to see their active sessions when visiting the website from a browser.

Prevent the session from resetting on each POST request with the Accept: application/json header and the correct bearer token.

Enable users to view and log out from all sessions except the current one, regardless of whether they are using the website or the mobile app.

Your assistance in resolving this issue and achieving seamless session management across both platforms would be greatly appreciated.